# Spring Framework ProblemDetail and ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring

In spring 6, ProblemDetail is available

```
@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
protected ProblemDetail handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {

    ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex.getMessage());
    problemDetail.setTitle("entity.not.found");
    return problemDetail;
}
```

Instead of returning directly a problemDetail, is there any utility to retun a

```
ResponseEntity<ProblemDetail>
```

Comment: Why would you ned to wrap it in a `ResponseEntity`? It should work by just returning that (unless you are extending the default implementation you cannot change the return type of the method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're many ways!

---

Using `@ResponseBody`:

```
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
protected ProblemDetail handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException ex, 
                                                      HttpServletRequest request) {
    ProblemDetail problemDetail = forStatusAndDetail(NOT_FOUND, ex.getMessage());
    problemDetail.setTitle("entity.not.found");
    return problemDetail;
}
```

---

With Spring `ResponseEntity` `static` mode:

```
@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<ProblemDetail> handleEntityNotFoundException(
        EntityNotFoundException ex, 
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    ProblemDetail problemDetail = forStatusAndDetail(NOT_FOUND, ex.getMessage());
    problemDetail.setTitle("entity.not.found");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(problemDetail);
}
```

Others status supported:

```
accepted()
badRequest()
noContent()
notFound()
unprocessableEntity()
```

---

Example with custom `body` and `header`:

```
@GetMapping("/customHeader")
ResponseEntity<String> customHeader() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header("Custom-Header", "app-custom-header")
        .body("Application custom body content");
}
```

---

Or with traditional constructor and custom status:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
```

---

#### Reference:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Comment: seem like duplicate to use ResponseEntity with ProblemDetail